# Using Python 3.6 when OS uses 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, python-3.6, fedora, python-3.7

I have a new laptop (dell xps 9570) on which I have installed fedora 29 which I will use for coding/data science.

Fedora 29 uses Python 3.7 but Tensorflow is not compatible with that version, so how can I use Python 3.6 without overriding system's default?

I have heard recently about virtual environment for Python but I don't know much about it, so I wonder is it possible to install Python 3.6 on a virtual environment?

Thank you

Comment: I am planning to use Conda but on their website only the version for 3.7 is available, the link for older versions does not work...

Comment: I tried to install it with Conda, `conda install tensorflow` and it keeps running at the message "Solving the environment"

Comment: I ran it for about 15min.

Comment: Ok I have let it run for a little longer and finally it proposed me to downgrade to version 3.6, so problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Python itself with pip; just Python packages.

You could use something like Conda. That provides a more separate (virtual) environment, including the Python executable. Conda also provides TensorFlow (up to version 1.12.0), which should make for a relatively easy installation:

```
conda create -n tensorflowenv python=3.6 tensorflow
```

Conda may take a while to solve the environment; just let it run, and it will likely install Python 3.6 in the Conda environment (whilst keeping your system Python 3.7), where you can then use TensorFlow.